# How to fill a freedrawn shape with colour

Tags: java, android, bitmap, gps, drawing

Im making a program using Java for android.
I'm drawing alot of rectangles on a bitmap using 4 lines connecting. ATM the lines are black and the background is white, i want to fill these "boxes" with colour and i cant figure out how to do it. 
to change from drawing 4 lines into making a box from the start is not an option, i have to draw lines that form a box.
im thinking of something that takes an argument of x,y in the middle of the "box" and then filling it with pixles until it hits the edge of the box but i cant get it to work.
it needs to be reapeteble too, i have alot of boxes to fill.

im using android 2.1 with API 7

Comment: are those boxes are rectangles/square in shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can quite simply do this with a `Path`. It works as you're talking about -- move from point to point "drawing lines" -- but when you're done you can fill it.

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
// set other paint parameters, like color...
...

Path path = new Path();
path.moveTo(startX, startY);
path.lineTo(startX, startY + 50);
path.lineTo(startX+50, startY + 50);
path.lineTo(startX+50, startY);
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Comment: thanks i think that will work!
il check it and i will add an explanation if it works or not.
cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use [Paths](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html). You can create your lines in a path, and then when you draw the path on the canvas, it will filled with the paint. You can also add a stroke to the path to add a border to the shape.

Comment: Im not able to use Paths.
i should have added that to the top but we are making an GPS and rendering the map.
we are doing this by getting ALOT of "nodes" from a text file.
each node is a point and from that point we are drawing lines and lines and lines until we have a map with houses and roads and land and water.
at this point we have "boxes" wich represent houses, thses are the boxes i want to fill.
so i dont know what is the starting line and the ending line of one house, i just have alot of lines that build houses.

Comment: Not following. You say you have a lot of lines and lines that make up boxes that are houses and you don't know which lines start and end a "house"... but you need to fill the houses. How are you going to figure out which lines make up the house so you can fill them?